# why assert when a udp6 port is closed in CTS case: android.net.cts.ListeningPortsTest::testNoListeningUdp6Ports

Tags: android, cts

When I running the CTS case: `android.net.cts.ListeningPortsTest:: testNoListeningUdp6Ports`, it failed, the traces are as follows:

> android.net.cts.ListeningPortsTest$ListeningPortsAssertionError: Found port listening on addr=00000000000000000000000000000000, port=43012, UID=1000 in /proc/net/udp6 at android.net.cts.ListeningPortsTest.assertNoListeningPorts(ListeningPortsTest.java:130)

This case get the udp6 ports information from the file:/proc/net/udp6, but if the state of an udp6 port is "07" which means CLOSED (as include/net/tcp_states.h has defined), why `isPortListening()` return "true" all the same. Then the case think the udp6 port is listening, and throw a exception.

So, I think maybe there is something wrong in this case, can anybody explain it? Thanks.

**Appendix:**

```
private static boolean isPortListening(String state, boolean isTcp) {
    // 0A = TCP_LISTEN from include/net/tcp_states.h
    String listeningState = isTcp ? "0A" : "07";
    return listeningState.equals(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `isTcp` argument was set to `false` in the method  `testNoListeningUdp6Ports`, but in `testNoListeningTcp6Ports` it was `true`